# Django - CSS doesn't show - Windows

Tags: css, django, django-urls

In my Windows DEV environment, I have the global.css file in "\SOWL\SOWL\static" folder.
my "templates" is under "\SOWL\SOWL\" as well.

My URLs.py has the following section:

```
import os.path
static = os.path.join(
os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'
)
(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',{'document_root': static}),
```

my base.html has the reference to:

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/global.css" />
```

but when I got the main page, the CSS doesn't show.

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps if you correct your base template css address like below it can work

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/global.css" />
```

if it don't work yet see the source of page 
in the source click on the url of css file
then you can see is it correct or not

---

Mohammad

Comment: No, it did not work. I took the first "/" (forward slash) from this line, now the HTTP trace shows "/catalog/static/global.css" and it was used to show "/static/global.css". In either case, CSS doesn't show up at all. Really puzzling.

[29/Jul/2012 23:21:00] "GET /static/global.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1634
[29/Jul/2012 23:25:31] "GET /catalog/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1102
[29/Jul/2012 23:25:31] "GET /catalog/static/global.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2199

Comment: I even tried changing the urls.py entry to " (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
  {'document_root': 'C:/SHIYAM/Personal/SuccessOwl/SOWL0.1/SOWL/SOWL/static'}),". That didn't work either. has anyone got this working in Windows at all?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
static = os.path.join(
os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'
)
```

To:

```
static = os.path.join(
os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'static'
)
```